# Lenovo (T500) battery manager

Tags: windows-7, thinkpad, battery-life

First of all, sorry for asking 2 questions on one day (the two are totally unrelated). I've got an extended brand Lenovo battery and a Windows 7, with the Lenovo made power manager for Windows 7. My sole problem is that I cant set a threshold for charge. Many of you may know that the laptop performs much better if it can access the backup power from the battery. The problem is that if you let it charge every time up, drain 1-5%, charge up, will kill the battery very soon. So I want to have a threshold. Charge when drops to 35% , Stop when reach 85%/80%. Sadly this doesnt really work on Win7. Can you provide me some problem report email address or something like that? Or any idea why this happens?

Comment: Sorry for asking 2 questions on one day? You can ask a hundred questions a day as long as they are of sufficient quality and are appropriate for Superuser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is fixed. (Maybe some updates did. Actually you need some time to make the battery remember the settings.)